# Disable time sync from the PDC for one machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain-controller, time-synchronization

I have a Windows Sserver 2012 PDC as virtual machine, I want to disable the time sync of its host with the PDC to avoid the loop. However I want to maintain the sync with all other machines.
How to disable time sync for a single machine?

Comment: `I want to disable the time sync of its host with the PDC to avoid the loop` - What loop?

Comment: THe one you have on that outdated server. MS fixed that in lader versions of the OS. This version IIRC the domain slowly falls behind as the DC can nt sync to outside as it gets overwritten by the host.

Comment: Host sync tis guest, but guest is the PDC then it will upgrade its host becausa it is a domain machine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should actually update your host and VM (2012 R2) and then just let it be? You are trying to do a lot to basically work around a **very long** solved problem.

Otherwise just disable time synchronization on the VM control panel. It is one of the services you can set on the VM configuration.

Comment: Not sure I have understood. I have win server 2012 (R1) as o.s. for both vms and hosts what shold I do? Just let hyper-v do everything?

Comment: No. Read my text. Possibly have someone explain it to you. Either upgrade to a not totally outdated version (seriously) and it is fixed automatically, or disable time sync in the hyper-v settings. It is an OBVIOUS switch for anyone bothering to actually go through the settings.

Comment: Update/Change SO is not a choice,  I found a time sync option for integration service, but this disable the sync  fom host to guest with Integration services. I asked how to stop the opposite: I want to avoid that the PDC (vm) changes the time to the host because this host is upgrading its time with its domain controller.